# How to format String in Java?

Tags: java

I am having this string `00 hours 01 minutes 25 seconds` stored in variable . How can I convert it into `00:01` hour and minutes in Java

what I tried is:

```java
String s = "00 hours 01 minutes 25 seconds";
System.out.println(s);
String []a = s.split(" , ");
String s2 = a[0] + a[2];
```

Comment: 1. `new` is not valid variable name - it is a reserved keyword. 2. You use wrong regex to split your string. Use s.split(" ") instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newS` will give the result you want

```java
String s = "00 hours 01 minutes 25 seconds";
System.out.println(s);
String []a = s.split("\\s");
String newS = a[0] + ":" + a[2];
System.out.println(newS);
```

Comment: String.split uses regex not substrings

Comment: Not with all whitespace characters, and the question didn't specify them

Comment: @tibetiroka I see your point in using `\s` instead of `" "`, but i usualy work with `" "` and I don't have a problem with that. Can you explain me when it will be a problem?

Comment: It might be a problem if your application is used in different regions or with different charsets, not everythink respects the UTF-16 conversion (or the standard ascii whitespace character code), or (if your string is imputted) it will not work with tabulators. However \\s supports any whitespace characters (it is short for the [ \t\n\x0B\f\r] regex). If you want to be really safe, you can use \\s* which matches any number of whitespace characters.

Comment: Well thank you very much for the explanation. I will also edit my amswer to use `\s`

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct, however your implementation has some issues.

```java
//String.split() uses regular expressions, this will split at spaces
String[] a = s.split("\\s");
String newString = a[0]+":"+a[2];
```

This should work.